# Set environment variable in Windows with c++ that is visible to subprocess

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I would like to know how to set a envirenment variable from a c++ program. I have some requirements.

- It needs to be visible to child processes that is being started with std::system()
- It needs to work in windows
- It needs to interface nice with std::string

Example dummy application

```cpp
void setVariable(std::string name, std::string value) {
  // This is what I dont know how to do.
}

int main(int, char **) {
   setVariable("hello", "there");
   system("echo %hello%");
}
```

I have experimented with `_putenv`, but my subprocess does not seeme to find the variable after it being set. And I do not find any example how to convert `std::string` to the input for [SetEnvironmentVariable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-setenvironmentvariable)

Comment: Check out std::string::c_str for converting the string

Comment: Yes the problematic part was converting to LPCTSTR, what that now is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set environment variables with [`_putenv_s`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/putenv-s-wputenv-s?view=msvc-160):

```
#include <cstdlib>

void setVariable(std::string name, std::string value) {
    _putenv_s(name.c_str(), value.c_str());
}

// if you need a wide version:
void setVariable(std::wstring name, std::wstring value) {
    _wputenv_s(name.c_str(), value.c_str());
}

int main() {
    setVariable("hello", "there");
    std::system("echo %hello%");
}
```